# When ^6 is raised in minor can it be approached by leap?

Tags: voice-leading, satb

[image]

At the end of this passage I have realized a figured bass with an ascending line using melodic minor. I am instructed to use 10ths in the outer voices for bar 5 so I obviously will have ^6 in the soprano for the IV chord. If I am to have the line ascend from this point it should use the melodic minor scale and ^6 will need to be raised to give me a major IV instead of a minor iv. However this produces a large leap of a diminished 5th. It does change direction but I'm not sure of this would be acceptable or not. My textbook does say dissonant leaps are good if the line changes direction but not sure about this one.

Edit: Here is another solution without using raised ^6.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That leap is a bit less common, but when I saw your question (before seeing your example), what you have written is exactly what I was singing in my head: a descending leap such that the raised scale-degree 6 could fill in that leap with ascending stepwise motion. Leaping *up* a tritone from the B♭ up to E♮ and then *continuing* in that ascending direction would have been an error, so your solution is the only viable one that I can envision.

Otherwise, the rest of your example looks perfect!

Comment: Thanks Richard. What about the 2nd solution I posted? I like the soprano better and dont need to leap to the raised ^6

Comment: @armani Yes, your second solution looks great as well! Since the scale-degree 6 is lowered, it *must* move down to D and not up to F#, exactly as you've done. Just watch for parallel octaves between the bass and tenor going into m. 4 :-)

Comment: thanks for showing me that.. hmm I dont like the doubling for the I6 anyway, I guess the only thing I can do is double the D of the I6 which is actually a better doubling note. The leap of a 4th in an inner voices is not ideal though